# Why has my account been blocked?

Tags: support, post-ban, accounts

My account has been blocked because I asked a question which wasn't well-received, but the documentation says that I have to review my questions and the system  will automatically take it into account.

I reviewed my question but the block is still there.

Also, I have good score on some questions, so is there a way for me to ask for a human review and get the block lifted?

Is there a way to ask for a review of my questions?

Comment: Paying attention to what reviwers do to improve your posts would help...

Answer (score 5):

Your account has not been closed, but automatically blocked from asking questions.

This is because you have a history of asking poor quality, badly received questions. When you were blocked you were presented with a page that included a link. That link was for a page that will give you information on how to get out of the block. This includes:

- Improving your existing questions.

  - Fixing the grammar and spelling.
  - Using proper English rather than txt speak (for example)
- Providing good, quality answers to other people questions

If you do these and the other things detailed on that page then you should be able to get the block lifted.

NOTE: This block is automatic and there's nothing that the moderators can do to get it lifted.

Comment: i fixed my grammar and i wrote better the questions also these questions have good points. i can't understand what the system wants. i must guess ?

Comment: @frank You have nearly 30 deleted questions which isn't going to help as these count against you.

Comment: @frank For starters, you should learn to use 'I' instead of 'i' for self reference.

Comment: @ChrisF i can not delete questions ? sorry this is crazy.

Comment: @frank - Yes you can delete questions, but if your questions are of poor quality it will count against you. Think of questions as a finite resource that can be used up. Ask them wisely and sparingly.

Comment: @ChrisF if my questions were of poor quality i didn't get the grade that i have and i didn't get points for my questions.

Comment: @frank - You have over 100 questions and 30 answers. Your reputation is not surprising given that level of activity. However, you don't have any outstandingly good posts.

Comment: @ChrisF i never told i have surprising reputation but i have points it means i did something good and in 100 question i can not guess which one is not good for the system you can understand the point ?

Comment: @frank - with 130 posts and only 449 reputation you have an average of less than one up-vote per post. This is not good. This is why your account has been blocked.

Comment: @ChrisF it is normal don't have an upvote for all questions and also for this i deleted some questions....do you think only "Perfect man" can ask here ... i can't belive this is the policy of the website.